# Can't pass data between ViewController and subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have been trying to create a number line app, which uses a UIScrollView class to add all the labels and ticks to the number line (basically creates the UI) so that I can achieve the illusion of infinite scrolling.

The problem is the number line is interactive, so there are inputs to the UIScrollView that I must access, such as selecting a number on the number line. 
However, whenever I try to pass data (such as numbers selected) from the UIScrollView class to a ViewController class it never works, as the value of the data in the ViewController stays at 0. Here is my code:

(ItemVC is the view controller that holds the scrollView, CalculationVC is the one I want to pass data to)

```
//In the UIScrollView class
let destVC: ItemVC = ItemVC()
destVC.number = myNumber

//In the ItemVC class
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)  {
    if segue.identifier == "Go" {
        let destVC: CalculationVC = CalculationVC()
        destVC.firstNumber = number
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing the problem is in the UIScrollView class code, as in ItemVC the value of number never changes to the appropriate value, it just stays at 0.

Answer (score 1):

should be like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if let calculationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? CalculationVC {
           calculationVC. firstNumber = number
      }
 }
```

you need to pass that to actual view controller that is going to be presented not to some instance of that controller class